# How to disable the auto resizing of Windows when you touch the top or bottom

Tags: unity

Can someone tell me how to stop the autoresizing behavior of Windows in Ubuntu 14.04 when you touch the top or bottom when resizing the window.

There is an undesirable effect of the the bottom resizing all the way to the bottom when you only want to resize the top, or vice-versa.

In the past it was possible to disable this effect by unchecking grid in CCSM.  Then came Unity Tweak tool which made it easy to remove.  You could remove it by turning off Window snapping and Hotcorners.

Now in Ubuntu 14.04 I have all those feature turned off and yet I can't resize only the top or only the bottom without the other end automatically moving.

Comment: We need a better system of each user trying out features one at a time.  Overwhelming the user with blanket one-size fits all upgrades is really time-consuming.  It generates a lot of web garbage as people all scramble to figure this out in there own ways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone having problems with the autoresizing this can be disabled in Compiz by:

Launch CCSM  -> Window Management -> Resize Window -> General -> Uncheck Maximize Vertically if Screen edge hit.