# Ubuntu 18.04: Unlock windows in GNOME (minimize togther) with ShellTile extension

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, window-management

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with the [ShellTile GNOME extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/shelltile/). My windows seem to be glued together. So when I minimize, say my chrome browser, the other window, say a terminal window, gets minimized as well.

This is very annoying and I don't know how to switch it off.

Maybe this happened after I installed the "compiz manager" (although I didn't change anything there)

I probably has something to do with the "snap window to one corner" function, because also when I change the width of the chrome window the terminal window width shrinks / increases accordingly (windows are always shown side-by-side).

Comment: This feature existed for some time in Gnome Shell. It has been removed again in subsequent versions. I do not know of a possibility to disable that behavior. See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/968155/17-10-how-to-disable-window-to-window-snapping-while-having-edge-snapping-enable?rq=1

Comment: @vanadium Turns out OP had ShellTile extension installed (from the self-answer) and it's a feature of the extension that can be turned off. Without any mention of this in the question made it extremely unclear to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: You can disable the behaviour using gnome-tweak tool:

[image]

[image]