# How do I disable two half-screen windows from resizing left-right together?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, window, gnome-tweaks, snap-windows

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.5

I commonly snap two windows to the edges so that they both take up half a screen. Then I will take one of those windows and make it a little bigger, so that it overlaps the other window.

I am not sure what this feature is called, but recently when I try and resize one of the half-screen windows to be wider, the second window resizes to be smaller in tandem. I would like this to never happen, and have the default behavior be that resizing causes them to overlap.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: The feature remained also in 20.04. I am not aware of a possibility to disable this behaviour.

Comment: I finally found my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/481627/how-to-disable-the-auto-resizing-of-windows-when-you-touch-the-top-or-bottom